# How to handle Github Webhook in Java?

Tags: java, github, webhooks

Simple question.
Got registered Payload URL on Github: using ngrok.com ([ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)) link like explained in Github documentation for Webhooks: [Creating Webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/creating/)

> ngrok definition: “I want to securely expose a local web server to the internet and capture all traffic for detailed inspection and replay.”

When i send POST request with payload from github on correct Payload URL the response code is 200, how can I handle that request/response and get payload (JSON) in java? With servlet or?
I have no idea where to start. Tried to search but nothing for Java :(

1. If i put ngrok.com/something, Eclipse console throw:
   `[WARN] 404 - POST /pas (127.0.0.1) 1368 bytes
   Request headers
     Host: ....ngrok.com
     X-Real-IP: 192....
     X-Forwarded-Proto: http
     Connection: close
     Content-Length: 5759
     Accept: */*
     User-Agent: GitHub-Hookshot/e9dfd89
     X-GitHub-Event: ping
     X-GitHub-Delivery: c5493000-b67e-11e4-8199-8b09d3d66948
     Content-Type: application/json
     X-Hub-Signature: sha1=b2947ce6a6de23f4274831523bae375d64e20021
   Response headers
     Connection: close
     Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
     Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
     Content-Length: 1368`
2. If i put good URL, status is 200. Response on Github Webhooks / Manage webhook:
   `Accept-Ranges: bytes
   Connection: keep-alive
   Content-Length: 1521
   Content-Type: text/html
   Date: Tue, 17 Feb 2015 10:17:46 GMT
   Last-Modified: Thu, 12 Feb 2015 09:06:18 GMT
   Server: nginx/1.6.2`

So the question is actually "How to handle that payload?"

- In documentation they use Sinatra and that's a big ? for me.

Sinatra code looks like this:
`require "sinatra"
require "json"
post "/payload" do
  push = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
  puts "I got some JSON: #{push.inspect}"
end`
New to this, sorry if its stupid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved, i used HttpServlet doPost method to fetch request, then from request i getReader() and read line so i can make JSONObject. My servlet is on page/Payload and Webhook is on http://server.com/page/Payload

```
public class Payload extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String aux = "";

    while ((aux = req.getReader().readLine()) != null) {
        builder.append(aux);
    }

    String text = builder.toString();
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(text);
        String teams_url = json.getJSONObject("repository").getString("teams_url");
        System.out.println("Teams URL:: "+teams_url);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }}
```

Comment: Did you consider using Gson and if so what influenced this approach over that?  I need to write a translator between github and this https://github.com/scmenthusiast/jira-scm-activity-plugin/wiki/JIRA-SCM-Activity-Plugin-REST-API

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [gitlab4j-api library](https://github.com/gitlab4j/gitlab4j-api). For example usage, have a look at simple review project, exactly here: https://github.com/gitlab4j/simple-cr/blob/master/src/main/java/org/gitlab4j/simplecr/service/GitLabWebHookService.java